# wp_list_categories exclude not working

Tags: categories, exclude

I'm try to exclude a specific category from a list of categories that a custom post has (in this case 'Uncategorized' - ID: 1).

I've tried `exclude`:

```
wp_list_categories([
  'include' => wp_list_pluck(get_the_category(), 'term_id'),
  'title_li' => '',
  'exclude' => 1
]);
```

But it still appears. How can I make sure it never appears, even if a post is tagged 'Uncategorized'?

Answer (score 4):

The `wp_list_categories()` function uses `get_terms()` behind the scenes, where the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/#parameters) for the `exclude` argument says:

> If `$include` is non-empty, `$exclude` is ignored.

Instead you could try to exclude the `term_id`  from the `include` values:

```
$include = wp_filter_object_list( 
    get_the_category(),   // Data
    [ 'term_id' => 1 ],   // Filter Data
    'NOT',                // Filter Option (exclude)
    'term_id'             // Pluck Data 
);
```

where we use [`wp_filter_object_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_object_list) to both *filter* and *pluck*. In general it could be better to check if the `$include` array is empty or not:

```
if( $include )
{
    // ... stuff above ...

    wp_list_categories( [
        'include'  => $includes,
        'title_li' => '',
    ] );

    // ... stuff below...
}
```

Comment: It seems to works for everything except when something is *only* tagged 'Uncategorized'... then it shows every category, including Uncategorized. Dang.

Comment: yes, that's expected, hence my comment about checking if it's empty or not. It's the same with WP_Query, we have to check for empty arrays before assigning to  the arguments. @DjangoReinhardt

Comment: I updated the answer to make to more clear @DjangoReinhardt

Answer (score 2):

I build some tricky code to exclude category having ID 1. I'm trying to exclude category(ID:1) even remove from pluck also. Your code has include and exclude both parameter and this conflict the result.

```
//List the pluck...
$exclude_cat_id = 1;
$list_pluck = wp_list_pluck(get_the_category(), 'term_id');

//Get exlude pluck(ID:1) index...
$exclude_pluck = array_search($exclude_cat_id, $list_pluck);

//unset excluded pluck...
unset($list_pluck[$exclude_pluck]);

//Get all category except ID=1
$arrCat = wp_list_categories([
  'include' => $list_pluck,
  'title_li' => '',
  'exclude' => array($exclude_cat_id),
  'exclude_tree' => array($exclude_cat_id),
]);
```

Hope this help you well!

Answer (score 2):

If my case, the only time I didn't want the list of categories to appear was if a post was 'Uncategorized'. The simplest solution in the end was just to use `in_category()`:

```
if (!in_category(1)) {
    // Display the categories this post belongs to, as links
    wp_list_categories([
            'include' => wp_list_pluck(get_the_category(), 'term_id'),
            'title_li' => ''
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $exclude = array();
   foreach (get_categories() as $category) 
   {$exclude[] = 1;}
   if (! empty($exclude)) 
   { $args .= ('' === $args) ? '' : '&';$args .= exclude='.implode(',', $exclude);}
   wp_list_categories($args);
```

Comment: Explanation for the code would be great!

Comment: just put in your functions.php file..

Answer (score -1):

How can I display only the specific category when accessing the posts related to that category? For example, I want to show only CSR Events under Categories When accessing posts related to CSR events. Here's the link to CSR post https://www.mi-eq.com/blood-donation-compaign/

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoTfk.jpg

Similarly, when visiting posts related to other categories, only the specific category will be shown. Is there any simplest to achieve that?

Comment: Hey David, you've posted your question as an answer. Create a new question instead.